# REACT.JS ¿Cómo hago para que en ciertas routes me muestre mi navbar con fondo y en otras routes no tenga fondo?

Tags: reactjs, navbar, headers

Tengo un inconveniente que no he podido solucionar, tengo un NAVBAR la cual necesito que solo en ciertas route deberá ser transparente y en otras tiene que mostrar el background. Es decir, cuando es transparente hago que se muestre el background por medio de SCROLL pero necesito que en otras rutas el scroll no funcione y que el background este siempre.
Todo esto lo manejo por medio de clases con CSS, **cuando quiero que sea con fondo le pongo una clase CSS y cuando quiero que sea transparente esa clase no existe.**

Les dejo mi código del componente header para que si alguien sabe la solución me la pueda indicar, por favor.

```
export function Header(){  
    const [ abrirMenu, setAbrirMenu ] = useState(false);   //state para el boton de menu en movil
    const [ navbar, setNavBar ] = useState(false);         //state que controla cuando poner el background y cuando no
    
    const hindleMenu = ()=>{setAbrirMenu(!abrirMenu)};

    window.addEventListener('scroll',  () => {                       //modifica el state de navbar cada vez que se hace scroll
        const cantScroll = window.scrollY;
        cantScroll >= 120 ? setNavBar(true) : setNavBar(false);
    });    
    
    
    return(
        <header>
            <WhatsAppButton/>     
            <nav className={`nav pdd_border navbar_all ${navbar ? "scrolling" : ""}`}>
                <Link to="/" key="0" className="logo">
                    <img src={navbar ? `${LogoConcept}` : `${Logo}`} alt="Logo luchin"/>
                </Link>
                <div className="group_btn">
                    <button onClick={hindleMenu} className={`btn-menu_nav ${abrirMenu ? "active" : ""}`}><i className={abrirMenu ? "fal fa-times" : "far fa-bars"}></i></button>
                </div>
                <div className={`container-items-nav ${abrirMenu ? "active" : ""}`}>
                    <div className="grup-items-scroll">
                        <div className="nav__navegacion">                            
                            <NavItems/>
                        </div>
                        <NavBotones isLogged = {false} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="bolsita">
                    <Link to={Routes.Bolsa.path}>
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 544.45 524.59"></svg>
                    </Link>
                    <div className="contador">
                        <p className="producto">0</p>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </nav>            
        </header> 
    )
}
```

Si alguien conoce la solución ayúdeme a solucionarlo por favor, soy nuevo en el framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, me gustaría decir que es buena práctica que en React los eventos se encuentren en un useEffect, ya que de esta forma cada vez que el componente se monta o se desmonta se debe añadir o quitar el evento para mejorar el rendimiento al evitar que se creen event listeners y evitar errores. En este caso:

```
const handleScroll = () => {
   const cantScroll = window.scrollY;
   cantScroll >= 120 ? setNavBar(true) : setNavBar(false);
}
useEffect(() => {
   window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);      
   return () => {
     window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
   };
}, []);
```

Sin saber el resto del código y dónde estás utilizando el header puedo proponerte dos opciones. Si el header lo estás importando en cada página y no como layout común, puedes pasarle una prop a true en las páginas de las rutas que te interesa mostrar el header no transparente. Ejemplo:

```
export function Header( solidBackground = false){  
    const [ abrirMenu, setAbrirMenu ] = useState(false);   //state para el boton de menu en movil
    const [ navbar, setNavBar ] = useState(solidBackground);         //state que controla cuando poner el background y cuando no
    
    const hindleMenu = ()=>{setAbrirMenu(!abrirMenu)};

    const handleScroll = () => {                   
        const cantScroll = window.scrollY;
        cantScroll >= 120 ? setNavBar(true) : setNavBar(solidBackground);
    };
```

Otra opción, suponiendo que estés usando la libreria react router y si el header está en un layout común para todas las páginas puedes utilizar el hook useLocation para saber en que página te encuentras y con esa información mostrar el header sólido o añadir el evento para siendo tranparente cambie a sólido con scroll.

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";  

export function Header(){  
        const [ abrirMenu, setAbrirMenu ] = useState(false);   //state para el boton de menu en movil
        const location = useLocation();            
        const [ navbar, setNavBar ] = useState(false);         //state que controla cuando poner el background y cuando no
        
        const hindleMenu = ()=>{setAbrirMenu(!abrirMenu)};
    
   const handleScroll = () => {
        const cantScroll = window.scrollY;
        cantScroll >= 120 ? setNavBar(true) : setNavBar(false);
   }
   useEffect(() => {
      if (location.pathname === "/rutaQuieroTransparente") {
         window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);      
         return () => {
           window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
         };
      }
      else {
          setNavBar(true);
       }
   }, [location]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme, la verdad me ayudo muchísimo tanto a resolver mi problema y a conocer que tenia que usar un useEffect, y creo que por eso me hacia un memory leaks cuando lo intente con otro método. De antemano muchas gracias.